# Iterate through Sites in a specific Level in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010

How do I iterate through all my sites from a specific level. At the moment, I have sites in the following location: http://myintranet.com/sites.

What I want to do is output all my sites from /sites, since I have other child sites beneath that level.

How can I do this?

At the moment, my code looks like this:

```
private void GetNavigation()
    {
        SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
        {
            using (SPWeb intranetSite = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Web.Url + "/sites/").OpenWeb())
            {
                SPWebCollection subSites = intranetSite.Webs;

                NavigationOutputHtml.Text = CreateNavigationHtml(subSites);
            }

        });
    }
```

I am doing all my iteration in the "CreateNavigationHtml" method. But I can't seem to pass the correct sites into my method from SPWebCollection.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/sites` is not a web site, it's a [Managed Path](http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/blogs/zach/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=30). In SharePoint, an IIS web site is a Web Application. Managed Paths allow SharePoint to have multiple Site Collections within a single IIS web site. And then SharePoint Sites are bundled within a Site Collection.

So to get all Sites within all Site Collections within the Web Application's `/sites` Managed Path, you will need code like this:

```
foreach (SPSite site in SPContext.Current.Site.WebApplication.Sites)
{
    try
    {
        if (SPSite.Exists(new Uri(site.Url)) && site.ServerRelativeUrl.StartsWith("/sites/"))
        {
            SPWebCollection subSites = site.AllWebs;
            NavigationOutputHtml.Text = CreateNavigationHtml(subSites);
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        site.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: I really appreciate your reply. I shall give this a go tomorrow. This has been bugging me all day. :-) Never thought it would be a site collection.

Comment: Hi Rich. How do I modify that code further so that it does not get the child sites of the site itself. For example, /sites/IT shouldn't go any further than that. I don't want to iterate through /site/IT/othersite. Thanks for any further help.

Comment: use RootWeb instead of AllWebs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsite.rootweb.aspx

Comment: Hi Rich, I used RootWeb. But I can't seem to get it to work. I changed the line: "SPWebCollection subSites = site.AllWebs;" to "SPWeb subSites = site.RootWeb;". 

Inside my "CreateNavigationHtml()" method I then loop through my subSites by doing the following: "foreach (SPWeb web in subSites.Webs) {...}".

Comment: That looks fine. You might want to post another question where you can outline this new problem in greater detail, since whatever is wrong now is most likely in {...}